# hay alguna manera de hacer una aplicación form, con la cuál puedas agregar, editar, borrar e imprimir parámetros de un reporte hecho en crystal report

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports

Tengo que entregar un programa el cuál estará conectado a una DB y tengo que usar Crystal report y C#, ya hago los reportes y están conectados con la base de datos, pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de hacer una aplicación form, con la cuál puedas agregar, editar, borrar e imprimir parámetros de un reporte hecho en crystal report, me explico.

en crystal r. puedes hacer todo eso, pero lo que busco es saber si hay alguna forma de que yo programe una app para extraer los datos de la base de datos e ir implementando dichos datos en el reporte.

Comment: seguro que si!!! al fin y al cabo, el query lo decidis vos... asi que si pasas otro query a CR, va a mostrar otros datos...

Comment: si pero así tendría que volver a diseñarlo yo verdad?  a lo que me refiero es ya tener como una hoja y el usuario final decida cuales datos quiere ver en su reporte, sin que el programador tenga que intervenir, a menos que quiera agregar más opciones de la base de datos, no sé si me explico.

Comment: Puedes usar [DataSet Tipados](https://pedroavilanu.wordpress.com/2013/07/28/crystal-reports-con-dataset-tipado/).

Comment: Parametros no es lo mismo que diseño del reporte.. estas hablando de diseño, o de parametros de la consulta?

Comment: el diseño ya lo tengo, lo que quiero es poder editar medianto un form creado por mí por ejemplo, donde el usuario pueda hacer el reporte de lo que quiera que esté en la base de datos que uso, o sea, hago un reporte mediante la app ya mencionada, con nombre e id, y como usuario ahora quiero otro reporte pero con apellidos nombres y fechas de cumple años sin el id por poner un ejemplo vago, alguien tiene una idea de un form así?

Comment: @Javifer2 puedes hablarme un poco más de esos datasets tipados?

Comment: A un reporte de crystal, le puedes indicar los datos que va a recibir en tiempo de diseño, mediante un xsd. Por ejemplo un xsd de parámetros. Conforme a lo que esperas recibir puedes programar su comportamiento, ya que puedes utilizar en el reporte tanto Vb como el lenguaje propio de crystal. Y cuando en tiempo de ejecución le asignas los datos de la bbdd, también le suministras los parámetros para determinar su comportamiento. [crsytal ado.net](https://archive.sap.com/kmuuid2/401c4455-a31d-2b10-ae96-fa57af5aec20/crnet_adonet.pdf)

Comment: También le puedes pasar parámetros, [Set parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589021/passing-parameters-to-crystal-reports-in-c-sharp) y luego trabajarlos en el reporte [With parameters](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-string-parameter.htm)